# Int can not hold the value of int.MaxValue

Tags: c#

I have the following two methods:

```
public int Average (params int[] array)
{
    if (array.Length > 0)
    { 
        double avg = Sum(ints) / arr.Length;        
        return (int)avg;             
    }        
    return 0;
} 

public int Sum(params int[] array2)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < array2.Length; n++)
    {
        total += arr[n];
    }
    return total;
}
```

But for testing purposes I tried adding the `int.MaxValue / 2` and `int.MaxValue / 2 + 4.` in the array. But why does the unit test fail, although the sum of the two values will be less than `int.MaxValue`?

Comment: Step through it in a debugger to see where your expectation deviates from reality.

Comment: I find the conclusion that `int` can not hold `int.MaxValue` curious. `int.MaxValue` is a constant of type `int`, so how does that work? Also, what would be the point of having a maximum value that is *impossible and wrong*?

Comment: As a side-note: `double avg = Sum(ints) / arr.Length` will not work as you expect. It divides two integers. For example if `Sum(ints) == 3` and `arr.Length == 2` then `avg` will be `1` and not `1.5`.

Comment: Side-note 2: Linq has built in functions `Sum` and `Average` which already do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> two values in the array[] :- int.MaxValue / 2 & int.MaxValue / 2 + 4.. but when i run the unit test it fails,, although the sum of the two values will be less than int.maxvalues?

No sir, the sum will be more than `int.MaxValue`:

```
(int.MaxValue / 2) + (int.MaxValue / 2 + 4) == int.MaxValue + 4 //...
```

You overflew the int max value.

Simple math: (x/2)+ (x/2 +4) == x+4

Comment: Nitpicking here: `int.MaxValue` is an odd value so `int.MaxValue / 2 * 2 != int.MaxValue`! The core of your answer is correct though. +1